# How can I reschedule all of my phone's remote (Push) notifications to specific time? is it possible in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am working on one iOS App in which I want to read all incoming remote notifications and reschedule them to my desired time.

So Let's say, I have reschedule all of my phone's push notification to 10am in morning, so all of my Phone notifications would come only at 10am in my Phone and there would be no any other notification except this time.

is this feasible in iOS? Does Apple allow this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean *all* notifications, not just ones from an app you may be developing. In which case, **no, it's not possible to affect when the notifications are shown.**

You could simply just turn your phone off (or put it in Airplane Mode) and turn it back on at 10am. :)

Apple does provide "Do Not Disturb" as a feature however. This doesn't stop notifications from arriving, but they don't alert the user when they do arrive. Instead there'll just a be a list of notifications waiting for you when you pick up your phone.